# Extremely slow USB 3 HDD transfer rate on one PC but not the other

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, usb, file-transfer

I have this Transcend Storage Jet external HDD. I was using it with my desktop Win 10 which supported USB 2.0. The transfer rate was satisfactory over 15MB/s. However, when I tried it on my new Lenovo ideapad 510 which supports USB 3.0 and using its USB 3.0 port, the transfer rate is going at a few 100 KB/s.

The copy window seems to pause a long time interval and only updates the speed and progress bar for just 1 frame every so often. Below is the CrystalDiskMark of this drive:

[image]

I've also tried the USB 2.0 ports on my laptop. The results are similar except for SeqQ32T1 and Seq which achieved > 30 MB/s

I've tried the following methods.

#### Disable Quick Removal Method

I've tried the most accepted answer of this: [Extremely slow USB transfer speed](https://superuser.com/questions/493295/extremely-slow-usb-transfer-speed) but the problems are:

1. It doesn't work
2. My old PC also does quick removal and there was no transfer problem.

#### TeraCopy method

However, using TeraCopy, the speed can achieve 32MB/s with the USB 2 port on my laptop. But this is just avoiding the problem, not actually solving it. Actually, the result is exactly the same using Explorer to copy.

Comment: Something is really wrong with your HDD. A normal external USB2 HDD should have a full-blown read-write performance of 35MBps on USB2 ports using files longer than 256kB. It would be helpful if you indicate precisely which HDD you are having this problem with.

Comment: @AliChen the HDD is a USB 3 Transcend StorageJet. I have also indicated the speed using a USB 2 port can exceed 30MB/s